# Cut number from string

Tags: string, bash, shell, awk, cut

I want to cut several numbers from a `.txt` file to add them later up. Here is an abstract from the `.txt` file:

```
anonuser   pts/25       127.0.0.1   Mon Nov 16 17:24 - crash (10+23:07)
```

I want to get the "10" before the "+" and I only want the number, nothing else. This number should be written to another `.txt` file. I used this code, but it only works if the number has one digit:

```
awk ' /^'anonuser' / {split($NF,k,"[(+0:)][0-9][0-9]");print k[1]} ' log2.txt > log3.txt
```

Comment: With awk: `awk -F[\(+] '{print $2}' file > new_file`

Comment: Why are you jumping out of and then back into awk with single quotes around `anonuser`? @Cyrus - your comment is the right solution so why not post it as an answer (after a tweak to get the syntax right: `awk -F'[(+]' '{print $2}' file`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '\(\K[^+]*' file > new_file
```

Output to new_file:

```
10
```

---

See: [PCRE Regex Spotlight: \K](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/pcre-regex-spotlight-k)

Comment: `\d` might be more relevant than `[^+]` since OP needs a number.

Comment: @Aaron: Thank you for this hint.

Comment: Also, if OP plans to collect these numbers and add them up later, `>>` might make more sense than`>`.

Comment: How can I search with this code for the user "anonuser" ? ^'anonuser' doesen't work

Comment: Use this: `grep -Po '^anonuser.*\(\K[^+]*' file`

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the `match()` function in `awk`?

```
$ awk '/^anonuser/ && match($NF,/^\(([0-9]*)/,a) {print a[1]}' file
10
```

How does this work?

- `/^anonuser/ && match() {print a[1]}` if the line starts with `anonuser` and the pattern is found, print it.
- `match($NF,/^\(([0-9]*)/,a)` in the last field (`(10+23:07)`), look for the string `(` + digits and capture these in the array `a[]`.

Note also that this approach allows you to store the values you capture, so that you can then sum them as you indicate in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following uses the same approach as the OP, and has a couple of advantages, e.g. it does not require anything special, and it is quite robust (with respect to assumptions about the input) and maintainable:

```
awk '/^anonuser/ {split($NF,k,/+/); gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",k[1]); print k[1]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

for anything more complex use `awk` but for simple task `sed` is easy enough

```
sed -r '/^anonuser/{s/.*\(([0-9]+)\+.*/\1/}'
```

find the number between a `(` and `+` sign.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the format in the file.
Can you use simple cut commands?

```
cut -d"(" -f2 log2.txt| cut -d"+" -f1 > log3.txt
```